# How do I select Multiple Pivot Items using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro in excel which will change a number of filters based on what is displayed in a list. I successfully acheived this for a single pivot items using the VBA code:

`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("1stAppPVT").PivotFields("Readable Subcategory"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("1stAppPVT").PivotFields("Readable Subcategory"). _
        CurrentPage = Range("$G$2").Text`

When I try to adjust the code to select multiple pivot items using the code:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("1stAppfuncPVT").PivotFields("Readable Application"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("1stAppfuncPVT").PivotFields( _
    "Readable Application")
    .CurrentPage = Range("$J$2").Text
    .CurrentPage = Range("$J$3").Text
    .CurrentPage = Range("$J$4").Text
    .CurrentPage = Range("$J$5").Text
    .CurrentPage = Range("$J$6").Text
End With
```

It only holds the selection for the final cell (J6). Is there a modification I can make to this code, or a different code I can try to select multiple pivot items based on either none pivot items, or a number of pivot items from a different table?